# Find range from stock quote

Tags: java, math

Using the share quote I need to find the range with the following input parameters:

price step : minimal price movement possible. Step = 0.01 mean that quotes can be 100.01, 100.1, but not 100.015. Can be > 1 for 'big' shares.

number of steps in range. Steps = 10 mean I need interval with 10 minimal price movements. Like [100.1 ; 100.2) Interval needs to be adjusted to minimal movement, so no [100.015; 100.15) intervals possible.

Input quote any double (6 digits after . is enough), may or may not obey price step rule (for example, direct value from stock market obeys, but average value is not). Obviously, quote should be in interval. I tried different approaches, but all of them fails.

Range is rather trivial:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable> {
    private T from = null;
    private T to = null;

    public Range(T from, T to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public T getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public T getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean contains(T value) {
        return from.compareTo(value) <= 0 && to.compareTo(value) > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Range{" +
                "from=" + from +
                ", to=" + to +
                '}';
    }
}


protected static Range<Double> getRangeFromPrice(double pips, int step, double price) {
    BigDecimal modifier = new BigDecimal(pips * step).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    BigDecimal begin = new BigDecimal(price).divide(modifier, 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).multiply(modifier);
    return new Range<>(begin.doubleValue(), begin.add(modifier).doubleValue());
}
```

This function works most of the time, for example for pips = 0.01 and step = 10

1. price = 132 Range{from=132.0, to=132.1} OK
2. price = 132.01 Range{from=132.0, to=132.1} OK
3. price = 132.1 Range{from=132.1, to=132.2} OK
4. price = 132.15 Range{from=132.2, to=132.3} <- ERROR, price not in interval

I  tried different rounding strategies, but all of them fails (in one example or another). Now I totally run out of ideas. How can I choose rounding strategy automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Decimal STEP = 0.1;  // floating-point 0.1 is always imprecise.
Decimal shifted = price / step; // make steps integral.
Decimal left = trunc(price) * step; // always ≤ price.
Decimal right = trunc(price + 1) * step;  // always > left.
return Range(left, right);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected static Range<Double> getRangeFromPrice(double step, int count, double price) {
    BigDecimal modifier = new BigDecimal(count * step).setScale(Common.PRICE_RESOLUTION, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal div = new BigDecimal(price).divide(modifier, Common.PRICE_RESOLUTION, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    BigDecimal begin = div.multiply(modifier);
    Range<Double> ret = new Range<>(begin.doubleValue(), begin.add(modifier).doubleValue());

    assert ret.contains(price);
    return ret;
}
```

I solved original issue with the following code. Price shouldn't be really double, I use number(19,6) in database, however in application I use double as BigDecimal is rather slow. 
If you want to use double, extra rounding is required.

This code pass my unit tests.